# How to work with finger eraser in android?

Tags: android, android-view

I have prepared one paint app.In my app we can draw any thing.It is working fine.Here i want prepare finger erase for erase paint.Eraser is working,but it is eraser all the drawn paint.I want to eraser only where i touch if drawn paint is there for that i wrote some code,

this my ondraw method,

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (myDrawBitmap == null) {
        myDrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBmpDrawCanvas = new Canvas(myDrawBitmap);
        mIntDrawArray = new int[myDrawBitmap.getWidth()
                * myDrawBitmap.getHeight()];
    }
    if (mBmpDrawCanvas != null) {
        myDrawBitmap.getPixels(mIntDrawArray, 0, myDrawBitmap.getWidth(),
                0, 0, myDrawBitmap.getWidth(), myDrawBitmap.getHeight());
        for (Path path : ILearnPaintActivity.mArryLstPath) {
            if (ILearnPaintActivity.mArryLstPath.contains(path)
                    && ILearnPaintActivity.paintAndEraserFlag == 1) {
                mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                        PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                mBmpDrawCanvas.drawPath(ILearnPaintActivity.mPath, mPaint);
            } else {
                mBmpDrawCanvas.drawPath(ILearnPaintActivity.mPath, mPaint);
            }

        }
        if (myDrawBitmap != null)
            canvas.drawBitmap(myDrawBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

}
```

draw paint is working fine.In same activity i have one button "Eraser". when we click on eraser button i assign flag for difference.Please help me how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

first u need to make clear what erase.

for vector base canvas it's delete vector element. 
for pixel base canvas it's mean draw with backgournd color. (or make it's transparency)

so in my point of view. when erase. you can change a Paint with backgournd color. and continue draw a very bold line on bitmap by touch.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
                mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);  // Bitmap erase color
                mPath.reset();       // your path
                mView.invalidate(); // your View Path
```